# Rails 7 and Bootstrap error in stimulus - failed to resolve module specifier bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I am following this tutorial: https://www.hotrails.dev/articles/rails-modals-with-hotwireEverything goes well until I create this stimulus controller file:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.modal = new bootstrap.Modal(this.element)
  }

  open() {
    if (!this.modal.isOpened) {
      this.modal.show()
    }
  }

  close(event) {
    if (event.detail.success) {
      this.modal.hide()
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

*"Failed to register controller: modal (controllers/modal_controller) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "bootstrap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."*

More info:
I have a bootstrap gem in gemfile, bootstrap CSS classes are accessible and available. But bootstrap js is not available and I dont know how to make it available to my Rails 7 app.

Also, I saw somewhere that I have to update the application.js file by adding these two last lines for bootstrap, and I would like to check with you if it is correct:

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers" 
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap" 
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
```

How do I make Bootstrap JS also available in my Rails 7 app?

Thank you

Update:

I also did the following:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

I updated the *app/javascript/application.js* file:

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "bootstrap"

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
```

and *importmap.rb* file:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"

pin "bootstrap", to: "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js", preload: true
```

But I am still not getting the Bootstrap JS loaded into my app, and I am still getting the same error in Console: *items:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "bootstrap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails uses importmaps by default, it doesn't use *node_modules* to find packages:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@popperjs/core@2.11.8/lib/index.js"
```

or just use an `importmap` command:

```shell
$ bin/importmap pin bootstrap
```

```js
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

// or just get what you need
import { Modal } from "bootstrap"
```

*https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails*